# Failed rspec test: returns the entire object instead of a string (only in rspec)

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I have a small game program written in Ruby, with a class for players and a class for a game. A player has a few attributes like name and health, and a game is an array of players with a title. One of the methods I wrote for my game class lists the names of the players in the array:

```
def list_names
    @players.each do |player|
            puts "#{player.name}"
    end
end
```

When I run this (in Sublime Text or with Pry) it works the way I'm expecting it to, with output that looks like this:

```
Margot
Cassandra
```

But in RSpec, I wrote the following tests (one for a game with one player, and one for a game with multiple players):

```
it "can list the names of players" do
    expect(@game.list_names).to eq("Margot")
end
```

and

```
context "with multiple players" do
    it "can list the names of players" do
        expect(@game.list_names).to eq("Margot\nCassandra")
    end
end
```

And they both fail. The output looks like this:

```
expected: "Margot"
        got: [#<Player:0x007f885b9e48d8 @name="Margot", @health=100>]
```

and

```
   expected: "Margot\nCassandra"
        got: [#<Player:0x007f885b93fc48 @name="Margot", @health=100, #<Player:0x007f885b93fbd0 @name="Cassandra", @health=150>]
```

So it looks like it returns just the name when I run it myself, but it's returning the entire object when rspec tests it. Any ideas? (Thank you so much in advance!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `each` method returns the array it acts on. The output of `puts` is not the same as the return value of `each`.

Comment: i.e. `@players.each` returns `@players`, which means `list_names()` returns `@players`.  In addition, puts adds a "\n" to the end of the string--if there is not already a newline at the end of the string, so the output of `puts "Margot"` is going to be `"Margot\n"`.  **but it's returning the entire object when rspec tests it.** See those brackets around the outside?  That's more than the object--it's an Array containing the object.